# How to convert one key/value of JSON files to .txt files?

Tags: python, json

I have ~400,000 JSON files. There is one key/value that I would like to extract into a .txt file for each JSON. (1 text file for each JSON. All JSON files are formatted the same.) I've looked into various options using python's pandas and json.loads, but I haven't been able to find a solution that works. (Below I'll include a shortened sample JSON file as an example, in case it's helpful. I want to extract "plain_text".)

```
    {
  "resource_uri": "https://www.courtlistener.com/api/rest/v3/opinions/9/",
  "id": 9,
  "absolute_url": "/opinion/9/pleasures-of-san-patricio-inc-v-mendez-torres/",
  "cluster": "https://www.courtlistener.com/api/rest/v3/clusters/9/",
  "author": "https://www.courtlistener.com/api/rest/v3/people/3246/",
  "joined_by": [],
  "author_str": "",
  "per_curiam": false,
  "joined_by_str": "",
  "date_created": "2010-03-13T23:42:04Z",
  "date_modified": "2020-03-03T09:02:12.634972Z",
  "type": "010combined",
  "sha1": "ce7f1af3436b00021ea3ee2f13107456b383cfa2",
  "page_count": 17,
  "download_url": "http://www.ca1.uscourts.gov/pdf.opinions/08-2388P-01A.pdf",
  "local_path": "pdf/2010/02/22/Rocafort_v._Mendez-Torres.pdf",
  "plain_text": "  United States Court of Appeals\n           For the First Circuit\n\nNo. 08-2388\n\n",
 "opinions_cited": [
    "https://www.courtlistener.com/api/rest/v3/opinions/103838/",
    "https://www.courtlistener.com/api/rest/v3/opinions/110435/",
    "https://www.courtlistener.com/api/rest/v3/opinions/110749/"
  ]
}
```

The end result I would like would be a text file for each JSON that is something like:

```
United States Court of Appeals
For the First Circuit

No. 08-2388
```

Comment: The question is not complete. You can make a plain text file from JSON (serialize it) in many ways. Can you show us what is the expected output for the example?

Comment: Also this JSON is not in the right format. You have a trailing comma in line 22 which is not allowed in JSON standard: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: _I've looked into various options using python's pandas and json.loads, but I haven't been able to find a solution that works._ Can you include those attempts, and clarify what the issue was?

Comment: This can be an option, https://github.com/ultrajson/ultrajson .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your JSON is in the right format you can use JSON library to load the JSON as a dictionary and then each key in JSON is a key in the dictionary:

```
import json 
  
with open('data.json') as json_file: 
    data = json.load(json_file) 
    print(data['plain_text'])
```

The output is:

```
  United States Court of Appeals
           For the First Circuit

No. 08-2388
```

You also have some extra space. If you want to remove them you can use:

```
import json 
  
with open('data.json') as json_file: 
    data = json.load(json_file) 
    field = data['plain_text'].split('\n')
    for l in field:
        print(l.strip())
```

the output is:

```
United States Court of Appeals
For the First Circuit

No. 08-2388
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have all your JSON files in the current directory and all are correct JSON files, you may convert all them at once:

```
import glob
import json
import os.path

for full_name in glob.glob("*.json"):
    with open(full_name, encoding="utf-8") as json_file:
        print(full_name)
        dic = json.load(json_file)
        text = dic["plain_text"]
        name, __ = os.path.splitext(full_name)
    with open(name + ".txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(text)
```

Each output text file will have the same name as the corresponding input JSON file but with `.txt` extension.

The line `print(full_name)` is only for information about names of processed files and is not needed for successfull work of the program.